# Android recieving classcastexception despite being in correct class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, classcastexception

I have an activity with a viewpager containing 2 fragments, inside each fragment contains a list, from this list a button can be pressed that creates a new fragment in the viewpager, this works fine until I create a new activity and close it, after the new activity is closed and I return to the previous activity pressing the button to create a new fragment again now gives a classcastexception, almost as if the closed activity is still open, but it is not, I have tried searching this issue and cant find any examples of this being encountered by anyone else which makes me wonder how this could be happening, I will post some code examples below, any help will go a long way thanks.

Click listener in ListAdapter:

```
            holder.rlStatusContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //add new comment fragment and set page
                try {

                    ((HomeFragmentActivity) activity).addCommentFragment(data.get(finalPosition));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Method in activity:

```
    public void addCommentFragment(ArrayList<Object> fragmentExtras) {

            list.add(NavigationFragment.newInstance(9, getApplicationContext(), this, fragmentExtras));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            pager.setCurrentItem(list.size());

    }
```

Error received:

```
12-13 13:37:50.177  17262-17262/test.test.com.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: test.test.com.test, PID: 17262
java.lang.ClassCastException: test.test.com.test.activities.NewPostActivity cannot be cast to test.test.com.test.activities.HomeFragmentActivity
        at test.test.com.test.adapters.ListHomeAdapter$4.onClick(ListHomeAdapter.java:462)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: are you sure you are in HomeFragmentActivity?

Comment: HomeFragmmentActivity is the only activity open when the button is pressed, thats what is the most puzzling about all of this, I am currently attempting to find a way to display the current class name to get more data

Comment: You can use getClass().getSimpleName()

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something that caused the activity property in your ListAdapter to be overwritten with the NewPostActivity, when it was the active activity?

Comment: The current activity is clearly NewPostActivity as the error message indicates.  Rather than trying to figure out how it isn't that, you should determine where the NewPostActivity is being created / entered, or why it isn't being finished when you expect.